# Close a batch file ran by c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a simpel program that runs a vulnerability scan on the given port and host. Now I have to find a way to close the batch file that is run from my c# form.
I have to be able to close the batch file from a button, even when its not finished yet. And i have no clue, nor did i find a way somewhere.

EDIT: Added more code, but still given the error "process doesn't exist in current context"

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (button10.Text == "Scan")
        {
            int port = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string strCommand = path + "/SystemFiles/nikto/nikto.bat";
            string host = textBox5.Text;
            Console.WriteLine(strCommand);
            richTextBox5.Text += "Starting Nikto Vulnerability Scan On " + host + " On Port " + port + System.Environment.NewLine;

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

            startInfo.FileName = strCommand;

            startInfo.Arguments = "-h " + host + " -port " + port + textBox6.Text;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            richTextBox5.Text += "Vulnerability Scan Started On " + host + " On Port " + port + System.Environment.NewLine;
            button10.Text = "Cancel";
        }
        else
        {
            process.Kill();
            button10.Text = "Scan";
        }



    }
```

Comment: are you familiar with the `waitforexit` method..

Comment: I believe OP wants to kill the process while it is still running, so `waitforexit` would be inappropriate.

Comment: #Michael, exactly ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the method kill in the process object

```
process.Kill()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer, but i can't get it to work, it keeps saying process doesn't exist in the current context...

Comment: Change the scope of you process variable put it outside of the "if" statement.

Comment: But when i place this `System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();` outside the if, it will create a new process when i click it again, and it wont be able to close the old one

Comment: Thats is true, you could create a field (private) for you form, and test if the variable is null, then you initialize it, otherwise you kill it.

Comment: I think i should look into something else, i tried the kill within the normal function, but after a 5s sleep, and it still doesnt close it :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full answer.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Diagnostics.Process _process;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_process == null || _process.HasExited)
        {
            _process = new Process();
        }
        else
        {
            _process.Kill();
            _process = null;                
            button10.Text = "Scan";

            return;
        }

        int port = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string strCommand = path + "/SystemFiles/nikto/nikto.bat";
        string host = textBox5.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(strCommand);
        richTextBox5.Text += "Starting Nikto Vulnerability Scan On " + host + " On Port " + port + System.Environment.NewLine;

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = strCommand,
            Arguments = "-h " + host + " -port " + port + textBox6.Text
        };

        _process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        _process.Start();
        richTextBox5.Text += "Vulnerability Scan Started On " + host + " On Port " + port + System.Environment.NewLine;
        button10.Text = "Cancel";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i try to add it to my code, it sadly enough is full of errors..

Comment: np, i fixed the errors, i just had to add System.Diagnostics before Process() and ProcessStartInfo, but when i click, it does the kill function, but doesn't kill the programm itself

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. You want the application (Windows Form) to exit?

Comment: no, i want the batch file that is executed to exit, but it doesnt, even when the kill() function is called

Comment: Ok, that very ODD, how did you access that?

Comment: I have tested locally, and its working locally, so not sure whats happening on your end. I was able to start the .bat file, kill it and restart. PS I made a small change to the code, that I am editing on the sample above.